# salesforce .net toolkit relationship query serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I created strongly type classes to use when using the toolkit to query salesforce

```
public class SFAccount
{        
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Account_Code__c { get; set; }
}

QueryResult<SFAccount> results = await _client.QueryAsync<SFAccount>(@"SELECT Id,
                                                                     Name,
                                                                     Account_Code__c
                                                                     FROM Account
                                                                     ORDER BY Id ASC");
```

This works fine as expected.
But when the query includes relationship columns using __r, I can't seem to get the toolkit to serialize my data to class object

```
public class SFLocation
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Account__c { get; set; }
    public string Account__r_Name { get; set; }
    public string Account__r_Account_Code__c { get; set; }           
}

QueryResult<SFLocation> results = await _client.QueryAsync<SFLocation>(@"SELECT Id,
                                                                Name,
                                                                Account__c,
                                                                Account__r.Name,
                                                                Account__r.Account_Code__c,
                                                                FROM Location__c
                                                                ORDER BY Id ASC");
```

The last two properties (Account__r_Name and Account__r_Account_Code__c) are not being populated and my query is valid and returns data

How would I construct my class so that the toolkit would be able to serialize the result data to the class?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @user3088377 no,I just used QueryAsync<dynamic> for for queries that used relationship columns

Comment: @user3088377 check out this reply from wade wagner, for the same question i asked him on his site https://disqus.com/home/discussion/developerrelations/nothing_but_net_8211_querying_objects_with_the_new_forcecom_toolkit_for_net/?utm_source=reply&utm_medium=email&utm_content=read_more#comment-1699465283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the [Force.com Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) for this?

In this case your `SFLocation` class should have a property of type `Account` that it called Account__r. And the Account class would have the `Name` and `Account_Code__c` properties.

You could check this in the debugger with a dynamic type. Set a breakpoint in the loop and inspect the `sfl`.

```
var dynamicLocations = await _client.QueryAsync<dynamic>(query );
foreach (dynamic sfl in dynamicLocations .Records)
{
    Console.WriteLine("location - " + sfl.Account__r);
}
```

Another alternative would be to get the raw JSON response from the query. Something like [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or Fiddler could be useful here. Then create the C# classes for Contact and Account from that JSON using http://json2csharp.com/