# SalesForce Rest API Mapping to .NET object

Tags: .net

I have the following C# code:-

```
            string query = @"select Unique_Contact_ID__c"
                        + ",Account.Account_Unique_ID__c"
                        + ",FirstName"
                        + ",LastName"
                        + ",Salutation"
                        + ",Phone"
                        + ",HomePhone"
                        + ",MobilePhone"
                        + ",Email"
                        + ",Title"
                        + ",Fax"
                        + ",Notes__c"
                        + ",MailingStreet"
                        + ",MailingCity"
                        + ",MailingState"
                        + ",MailingPostalCode"
                        + ",MailingCountry"
                        + ",Account.Name"
                        + ",LastModifiedDate"
                        + ",IsDeleted"
                        + ",Main_Accounts_Contact__c"
                        + ",Main_Sales_Contact__c"
                        + ",Company_Type__c"
                        + " from Contact "
                        + " ORDER BY Id LIMIT 10";



            var contacts = new List<Contact>();

            log.LogMessage("Running query to get data from salesforce");

            var results = await client.QueryAsync<Contact>(query);

            contacts.AddRange(results.Records);
```

Note the two columns in the query that have a dot(.) in them - Account.Account_Unique_ID__c and Account.Name

Contact is a .NET class.  I can't have dot(.)'s in my class property names so when this code executes all the other properties of the class are populated beautifully but the two with dots are null

I noticed that SOQL does not have field aliasing.

What is the best way around this?

Comment: Related [salesforce .net toolkit relationship query serialization](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/56523/102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the [Force.com Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) for this?

In this case your `Contact` class should have a property of type `Account` that was also called Account. And the Account class would have the `Account_Unique_ID__c` property.

You could check this in the debugger with a dynamic type. Set a breakpoint in the loop and inspect the `cont`.

```
var dynamicContacts = await client.QueryAsync<dynamic>(query );
foreach (dynamic cont in dynamicContacts.Records)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contact - " + cont.Account);
}
```

Another alternative would be to get the raw JSON response from the query. Something like [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or Fiddler could be useful here. Then create the C# classes for SFLocation and Account from that JSON using http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Yes correct Force.com Toolkit for .NET.  Adding a property of type Account to the Contact class worked a treat.  Thanks!